# Backbone.js bind this to setInterval

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to access `this.collection` from within a `setInterval`.  However, this isn't bound.  I can't seem to figure out how to bind it so that `this` can access the collection, not the `setInterval` object.

Here's a snipit from my View.

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this);
},
start: function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) { 
      console.log(item.id);
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/bind) the value of `this` you need when you set up the callback:

```
setInterval(function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) { 
        console.log(item.id);
    });
}.bind(this), 5000);
```

Don't forget to include the shim from the above MDN page if you need IE8 compatibility.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Is that shim only for this method of binding, as oppose to underscore's bind?

Comment: @dave No idea whatsoever. The source code of both looks more or less similar though.

Comment: @muistooshort Please note the last sentence in the answer. Possibly also look at the source code of the mentioned shim.

Comment: Hmmm... kind of with mu is too short on this. Why include the shim when you have underscore's bind available to you? 

this.collection.each(_.bind(function() {...},this));

Comment: @BrendanDelumpa Because I'm not terribly familiar with Underscore, so I answered with what I knew works. I never said to *not* use their implementation, just that I have no idea if it does the same.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, I guess I'll go with underscore to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this);
},
afterInterval: function() {
  this.collection.each(function(item){ 
    console.log(item.id);
  });
},
start: function() {
  setInterval(this.afterInterval, 5000);
}
```

`afterInterval` is now a callback and it has access to `this` of the view.